# Why "REPL command prompt" doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm reading nodejs documentation but sometimes my code doesn't work as the doc expected.

ex. [Run REPL from javascript file](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-use-the-nodejs-repl#run-repl-from-javascript-file)
as the doc said, I'm adding the following code in my `repl.js` file:

```js
const repl = require('repl');
const local = repl.start(prompt);
```

Then, running the file in the command line:

```sh
node repl.js
```

**BUT**

unfortunately, I'm facing an error!!!

```sh
const local = repl.start(prompt);
                         ^
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You haven't defined the `prompt` variable - "_the prompt is a string that accepts the prompt which shows when repl starts, default is '>'_" - you should define your own variable

Comment: @NickParsons  Thanks.
Why did you answer as a comment?! 

Comment: @AshkanHeidary: when the actual issue is not really related to the question, people sometimes don't even bother to answer but just leave a comment. An intention is that your question could possibly be closed. Your issue is a general issue with an undefined variable, not at all related to REPL. Thus, future readers won't possibly benefit from getting here in case of actual, real problems with the REPL.

Comment: @WiktorZychla
